# Создание прав по умолчанию

Tags: python, django

Требуется в приложении задать права по умолчанию. Реализовал через миграцию данных (создал пустую, и в *RunPython* добавил заполнение).

Но она выполняется до заполнения таблицы `auth_permission`. Приходится сначала применять юзерские миграции, затем всё остальное.

Как можно сделать так, чтобы она выполнялась после заполнения? Или, может быть, есть другой метод решения данной задачи?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно корректно заполнить свойство `dependencies` у класса `Migration`:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
       ('<имя_приложения>', '<имя_миграции>'),
    ]
```